# Unity mouse input on mobile

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, input

I am new to `Unity` and I am making a first-person game. I followed this video https://youtu.be/_QajrabyTJc and when I try on `Unity` Remote 5 and the camera is not rotating. The code is here :

```cs
     public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;


    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;



        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }
```

How can I solve this problem? Or is it only because I am using Unity Remote 5, but not on Android mobile?

Comment: Pretty sure `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X/Y")` should not work on mobile. 
What will work is using `Input.MousePosition`, storing it every frame, and in the next frame getting the delta `var delta = lastMousePosition - Input.MousePosition;` and this will give you the x/y movement amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For touch input on a mobile device you would rather want to use the `Input.touches` and do something like e.g.

```
// I would use a Vector2 here in order to be able
// to have a different sensitivity for the two axis
public Vector2 mouseSensitivity = Vector2.one * 100f;
public Transform playerBody;

private Vector2 startPos;
private float startRot;
private Quaternion originalBodyRot;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                startPos = touch.position;
                startRot = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
                originalBodyRot = playerBody.rotation;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                var delta = Vector2.Scale(touch.position - startPos, mouseSensitivity);

                var newRot = Mathf.Clamp(startRot - delta.y, -90, 90);
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (newRot, 0, 0);

                playerBody.rotation = originalBodyRot * Quaternion.Euler(0, delta.x, 0);            
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `touch.position` is in **pixel** space so you might have to adjust your sensitivity.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently added Mouse & Keyboard support to Unity3D.
So it works just like it does on PC.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/mobile-input-capture-221017